# Bintray and jCenter are not really sync their changes automatically

Tags: android, gradle, artifactory, bintray, jcenter

There is a weird issue I am facing here. I had my Android library uploaded to Bintray and when I requested to add to jCenter everything worked fine.

The library was this:

http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/kostasdrakonakis/button_preference/1.0.0

So I could see something like this using gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.kostasdrakonakis:button_preference:1.0.0'
```

But then I changed the artifact id to this:

Instead of **button_preference** to **button-preference**

So I could expect something like:

```
compile 'com.github.kostasdrakonakis:button-preference:1.0.0'
```

But since I see it like this:

https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter?filterByPkgName=button-preference

but not in jcenter:

http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/kostasdrakonakis/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since  you have requested to add the below to jcenter:
com/github/kostasdrakonakis/button_preference

Only changes in this path would be synced to jcenter.

Once you have changed the artifact-id, you have changed the path JFrog has approved to you and now you have a new path (com/github/kostasdrakonakis/button-preference) which is not synced with jcenter.

We have linked your packages to your new path.
For any issues, please contact JFrog Support.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Just an suggestion for future: Why this relink cannot happen automatically everytime it detects a new artifact for same group id?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @matrix, the linking to jcenter is on the artifact id level and not on the group id level, therefore, for example in case you want to link another package on the same group id, you will have to submit new inclusion request, it wont be synced automatically ( the approval and the sync is on the artifact id path and not on the group id path)